# In C, does sizeof measures its result in octet bytes or chars?

Tags: c, char, sizeof

Although a `char` is composed of `1 byte` on all compilers I know, I was under the impression that `C` doesn't guarantee the length of a `char`, it only guarantees that `char < short < long`.
Therefore I assumed that `sizeof` measures its result in `char`s in order to abstract from the platform it's running on. To make it more general, I thought that `size_t` is defined in terms of `char`.

But now, as far as I can see searching on google, it appears that `sizeof` does return its result in `bytes`.

Was I completely wrong in my assumption or is there more to it than that?

Comment: *"Although a char is composed of 1 byte on all compilers I know,"* - `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, but a byte is *not* defined to be 8 bits.  `CHAR_BIT` will tell you how many bits are in a byte on your machine.

Comment: I edited because when you say "byte" you seem to mean "octet". I wasn't sure whether the edit is good, because while it is obvious what you meant, it hides your confusion from furter answerers.

Comment: The C standard requires `CHAR_BIT >= 8`. POSIX imposes a stricter requirement on top of that, that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, so only a non-POSIX implementation can have bytes bigger than 8 bits. You're not likely to encounter a system with `CHAR_BIT > 8` unless you work with [DSPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor). Still, you should use `CHAR_BIT` in your code rather than assume 8 bits per byte.

Comment: My copy of K&R says about `sizeof` that it yields "an integer equal to the size of the specified object or type in bytes", so, if `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1`, then that means a `char`is always one byte long. But one byte does not have to be 8-bit long.

Comment: BTW: C guarantees that `char <= short <= long`.  They could all be the same size.  Each have minimum bit size (8,16,32).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` ***is*** the C data type that represents a *byte*; they're conceptually the same.

If you're asking whether the result is always in **octet**'s (8-bit values), the answer is **no**; it's in bytes (`char`s), and if a byte happens to have a different number of bits then the result will be in terms of multiples of that many bits.

Answer (score 10):

The unit used by `sizeof` is  the `char`. One of the axioms of the language is that `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Hence, for systems where `char` is larger than 8 bits, `sizeof` does not measure in 8 bit units.

Answer (score 7):

The units for `sizeof` is chars.

However, C defines a byte to be the size of a char, and not the more common usage where a byte equals 8 bits.

If you want to know how many bits a char is, use the `CHAR_BIT` constant in `<limits.h>`